# Sample from dataframe by groups based on a certain distribution

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, distribution, sample

I'm trying to sample from a data frame but with the condition that the sample represents the distribution in terms of a certain criterion in my case. The data frame is structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Locaton = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', ...),
                 Veg_Species = c('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', ...),
                 Date_Diff = c(2, 5, 2, 0, 4, 4, ...))
```

It is important to know that the number of each `Veg_Species` differs. That means `X` has 25 occurrences, `Y` 45 and `Z` 78 for example. And now I want to sample from the different `Veg_Species` based on the distribution in terms of `Date_Diff` of the ***smallest*** sample. In that case that would mean sampling from every species in terms of `Date_diff` distribution from `X`.

I thought that I can do that with `dplyr`:

```
sample.species <- df %>%
  filter(Veg_Species == 'Z') %>%
  sample_n(25, replace = TRUE)
```

But that obviously only samples randomly from all `Veg_Species` with the name `Z`.

How can I take the distribution into account too?

For a more detailed example, click [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2a26bf2c69bfd76e8ddcecd1c3739a31/ex.csv).

Comment: @RonakShah http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2a26bf2c69bfd76e8ddcecd1c3739a31/ex.csv I hope this helps. I want to filter by species and sample from every species taking the distribution of Date_Diff of the smallest sampel into account. In this case "Artemisia filifolia" is the smallest sample with 26 entries. I want to sample from "Adenostoma fasciculatum" for example the exact same size (26) with regarding the distribution in terms of Date_Diff from "Artemisia filifolia".

Comment: what you mean with samping according to distribution? sampling a subset preserving distribution?

Comment: Yes, as is edited. I want to sample from "Adenostoma fasciculatum" for example the exact same size the "Artemisia filifolia" (26) sample has, with regarding the distribution in terms of Date_Diff from "Artemisia filifolia".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try kernel density estimation for the distribution of `Date_Diff`.

**1. Data and package**

```
df <- read.csv("http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/2a26bf2c69bfd76e8ddcecd1c3739a31/ex.csv", row.names = 1)
library(dplyr)
```

**2. Find the smallest species**

```
df %>% count(Species)

#                   Species  n
# 1 Adenostoma fasciculatum 95
# 2     Artemisia filifolia 26
# 3  Eriogonum fasciculatum 41
# 4              Tamarix L. 27
```

**3. Kernel density estimation of distribution and linear interpolation**

(*Reference: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78775/218516*)

```
val <- df$Date_Diff[df$Species == "Artemisia filifolia"]
dist.fun <- approxfun(density(val))
```

**4. Sampling**

(*`sample_n()` has been superseded in favour of `slice_sample()` since `dplyr 1.0.0`.*)

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 26, weight_by = dist.fun(Date_Diff)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**5. Check**

```
df2 %>% count(Species)

#   Species                     n
#   <chr>                   <int>
# 1 Adenostoma fasciculatum    26
# 2 Artemisia filifolia        26
# 3 Eriogonum fasciculatum     26
# 4 Tamarix L.                 26
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to sample over your data set, but maintain the distribution of `Date_diff` that is present in the X subset.

First you need to determine what is present in the X subset. I made some fake data that seems to look like yours:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Location = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 148, replace = TRUE),
                 Veg_Species = c(rep("X", 25), rep("Y", 45), rep("Z", 78)),
                 Date_Diff = trunc(runif(148, 0, 10)))
```

Now, we need the distribution of `Date_Diff` for `Veg_Species = X`. We can do that with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x_dist <- df %>%
  filter(Veg_Species == "X") %>%
  group_by(Date_Diff) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
x_dist
A tibble: 8 x 2
  Date_Diff count
      <dbl> <int>
1         1     2
2         2     6
3         3     5
4         4     3
5         5     3
6         6     2
7         7     2
8         8     2
```

Now we filter the original data, `nest_by(Date_Diff)` and sample each `data` by the `count` in `x_dist`.

```
set.seed(345)
df_sample <- df %>%
  semi_join(x_dist) %>%  # Remove all rows with Date_Diff not in x_dist
  nest_by(Date_Diff) %>%
  inner_join(x_dist) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(data[sample(1:nrow(data), # sampling the data
                                 size = count, 
                                 replace = TRUE),])) %>%
  summarize(data) %>%    # unnesting the data
  select(Location, veg_Species, 
         Date_Diff, -count) # reordering columns and removing count
df_sample
# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups:   Date_Diff [8]
   Location Veg_Species Date_Diff
   <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
 1 C        Z                   1
 2 A        Z                   1
 3 A        Y                   2
 4 C        Z                   2
 5 B        X                   2
 6 B        Z                   2
 7 B        X                   2
 8 B        X                   2
 9 A        Y                   3
10 A        X                   3
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument `prob=` in `sample()` is a vector of weights for each element of sample. My idea is to use the indexes for each row and the vector of weights for the sampling. That would preserve the distribution.

```
sample_by_distribution <- function(df, dist_weights_col, n, replace=FALSE) {
  sampled_indexes <- sample(x=1:nrow(df), size=n, replace=replace, prob = df[, dist_weights_col])
  df[sampled_indexes,]
}
```

Sample by taking into account the distribution weights in your case:

```
sample_df <- sample_by_distribution(df, "Date_Diff", 25, replace=FALSE)
```

This would sample 25 rows of `df` while the probability for each row follows the "Date_Diff" column. Therefore, the distribution of "Veg_Species" should be also preserved.